# Map chart not working properly (movie not loaded)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

**I created map chart:**

Map type United States of America then select Country Maps and States with default page attributes and map attributes.

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT null link, region label, value Populations
FROM (
SELECT 'Florida' region, 18328340 value FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alaska' region, 686293 value FROM dual)
```

When I try to run application then nothing showing. Right click on empty area then showing "Movie not loaded". Adobe Flash Player version 32 and Google Chrome version 79

Oracle Apex 18.2.0.00.12 and Oracle Database 11g

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The flash content needed to render AnyCharts maps no longer ships with APEX. See this doc:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/downloads/apex-181-known-issues-addendum-4491404.html

Part E gives you two options. You can add the files yourself, or move to Oracle JET. You can learn about Oracle JET maps here: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet-420/jetCookbook.html?component=thematicMap&demo=default